# Illegal string offset?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using customization the wordpress header then i am getting error while using this code:

```
$qes=mysql_query("SELECT sm.subject_name from user_common_master as ucm
        left join tutor_institute_subject_master as tism on tism.tutor_institute_uid = ucm.uid
        left join subject_master as sm on sm.subject_id= tism.subject_id
            WHERE ucm.uid='$uid'");
$res=mysql_fetch_array($qes);
```

and to print the data

```
<?php foreach($res as $ress): {$ress['subject_name'];echo ' , ';} endforeach;?>
```

please suggest me how to remove this warning error

Comment: The way your code is set up `$res` will hold the data you're looking for (not `$ress`). Also the `:` at `$ress): {` is superfluous.

Comment: <?php foreach($res as $ress){  echo $ress['subject_name']. ' , '; }?>
Also giving same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$res` is already a single row. `foreach` is now looping over the *columns* of the row, which are strings, of which `'subject_name'` is an illegal offset.

Do a bit of debugging with `var_dump` and rethink your algorithm - I can't guess exactly what you intended to do here.

Comment: while i am using var_dump
its giving
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  NULL
  ["subject_name"]=>
  NULL
}